# Does stilted english means that the writer is dumb in using the langauge?

Tags: style

Does stilted english means that the writer is dumb in using the langauge? Or can it be said to be their style?

Some said that it can easily be pointed out if someone is not a native English speaker. One way to know it is, if the writing is silted. So does silted writing really means that the writer is not a native speaker, and that being this he/ she is not good in using the language?

This question, for example:

1. Is there anyone to expect, that in social tasks he seeks to complete, he requires 
   spirituality?

Comment: It's possible that I'm not understanding the question. But it sounds like you're saying, if someone writes badly in a language, are they a bad writer in that language?

Comment: Speaking about using the English language: "stilted" and "silted" mean two different things.

Comment: This question really needs context; at the moment, it's asking us for an opinion about a piece of writing which we haven't seen. Closing this for now, but please consider editing so it's not asking for vague opinions and we'll consider re-opening.

Answer (score 2):

According to its definition:

**Stilted**: Stiffly or artificially formal;

> Does stilted english means that the writer is dumb in using the langauge? Or can it be said to be their style?

Why dumb? It means that the writer does not have enough experience with the language, so his writings look too formal or too "*robotic*", because the way they are written is a mathematical way.

**Example**:

**STILTED ENGLISH**

> P1: Would you happen to have any milk in your refrigerator?  I ruined my last cup when I added the wrong spice and now my carton is empty.
>
> P2: No, I'm afraid I have no milk.  But whilst your here, would you
>   mind, what is the name of your plumbing specialist?

**FLUID ENGLISH**

> P1: Do you have any milk?  I had to dump my last cup when I
>   added the wrong thing from my recipe to it.
>
> P2: No, sorry, but hey, what's the number to your plumber?

**Source**: http://the-ink-slinger.blogspot.com.es/2010/07/stilted-language.html

Apart from this, you have some mistakes in your question:

- Does it MEAN (no final -s)
- Silted is not the same as s-**t**-ilted.